# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

I am receiving this error from my JavaScript code:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function repartition()
{
    var principal_p             = <?php echo $data23['principal_p'] ;?>; 
    var principal_c             = <?php echo $data23['principal_c'] ;?>; 
    var interets_p              = <?php echo $data23['interets_p'] ;?>; 
    var interets_c              = <?php echo $data23['interets_c'] ;?>; 
    var clause_penale_p         = <?php echo $data23['clause_penale_p'] ;?>; 
    var clause_penale_c         = <?php echo $data23['clause_penale_c'] ;?>;
    var domages_interets_p      = <?php echo $data23['domages_interets_p'] ;?>;
    var domages_interets_c      = <?php echo $data23['domages_interets_c'] ;?>;
    var art700_cpc_p            = <?php echo $data23['art700_cpc_p'] ;?>;
    var art700_cpc_c            = <?php echo $data23['art700_cpc_c'] ;?>;
    var art475_1_cpp_p          = <?php echo $data23['art475_1_cpp_p'] ;?>;
    var art475_1_cpp_c          = <?php echo $data23['art475_1_cpp_c'] ;?>;
    var art_441_6_cc_p          = <?php echo $data23['art_441_6_cc_p'] ;?>;
    var art_441_6_cc_c          = <?php echo $data23['art_441_6_cc_c'] ;?>;
    var frais_ar_p              = <?php echo $data23['frais_ar_p'] ;?>; 
    var frais_ar_c              = <?php echo $data23['frais_ar_c'] ;?>;
    var agios_p                 = <?php echo $data23['agios_p'] ;?>; 
    var agios_c                 = <?php echo $data23['agios_c'] ;?>;
    var depens_p                = <?php echo $data23['depens_p'] ;?>; 
    var depens_c                = <?php echo $data23['depens_c'] ;?>;   
    var frais_execution_p       = <?php echo $data23['frais_execution_p'] ;?>; 
    var frais_execution_c       = <?php echo $data23['frais_execution_c'] ;?>;  
    var contrib_aid_juridiq_p   = <?php echo $data23['contrib_aid_juridiq_p'] ;?>;
    var contrib_aid_juridiq_c   = <?php echo $data23['contrib_aid_juridiq_c'] ;?>;  
    var frais_greffe_p          = <?php echo $data23['frais_greffe_p'] ;?>;
    var frais_greffe_c          = <?php echo $data23['frais_greffe_c'] ;?>;
    principal = document.getElementsByName("principal_s");
    document.getElementsById(nprincipal)= (principal*principal_p)/100;
}
</script>
```

The line that causes the error is the line with `document.getElementsById` in it.  Why is it causing the error?

Comment: Yes - the last line is indeed an error, as you attempting to assign a value not to a variable but to an HTML element. What were you intending with this line?

Comment: You should really look into json and php's function json_encode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php this will save you a lot of trouble about parsing data from php to javascript

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to assign the result of a function call which is never a Reference that can be assigned to but a value instead so you cannot assign to it. This is why you get that error.

---

As for fixing your code in general, that is outside of the scope. I can help you with some guesses:

You can set the `.innerHTML` of the element to the value like follows:

```
   document.getElementById("nprincipal").innerHTML = (principal[0].value*principal_p)/100;
```

I also fixed:

- `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`
- `principal` is a live nodelist of what I assume is a single input element, so I am fetching the `.value` of it by `[0].value`
- use a string in the `getElementById` as `nprincipal` is not defined in your code

Comment: All of these are guesses, you should provide more information

Comment: actualy i have this code

 principal = document.getElementsByName("principal_s").value;
 document.getElementById("nprincipal").value= principal;

and it put on the input typ text UNDEFINED.

And in the following input <input name="principal_s" type="text" id="r<?php echo $data12['ordre_principal'] ; ?>" size="10"   /> i have an amount

Comment: in fact the amount in principal is defined when I onblur the input because, it's displayed in an other function:<input type="text" name="montantacompte" id="montantacompte" onblur="hono();payment();imputed();repartition()"    />

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do in your code? At the moment you are assigning the result of your calculation to a DOM element, if you want to display the result on the page then you probably want to do this:

```
document.getElementById(nprincipal).innerHTML = (principal*principal_p)/100;
```

Comment: now it says Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementsById'

Comment: It should be document.getElementById - I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsById(nprincipal)= (principal*principal_p)/100;
```

is the error...if it is some form element it should be

```
document.getElementById(nprincipal).value= (principal*principal_p)/100;
```

Edit

Also

```
principal = document.getElementByName("principal_s");
```

should be

```
principal = document.getElementByName("principal_s").value;
```

Comment: There is no `.getElementByName`

Comment: now it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null index.php:337
repartition index.php:337
onblur

Comment: You can use `getElementsByName(name)` this will return you a NodeList you can iterate using `for`, `while` to get the first in the nodeList simply add `[0]` like an array

Comment: yep..my bad..i agree with Andreas

Answer (score 0):

To extend a comment i made to op.

Look into json and javascript objects. This will save you a lot of trouble parsing the data from php to javascript:

```
var data23 = <?php echo json_encode($data23) ;?>
```

This will make an Object looking like this:

```
{
    principal_p: <?php echo $data23['principal_p'] ;?>,
    principal_c: <?php echo $data23['principal_c'] ;?>,
    interets_p: <?php echo $data23['interets_p'] ;?>, 
    interets_c: <?php echo $data23['interets_c'] ;?>,

    ....
}
```

you can now reference to `data23.principal_p` to get the data parsed from `<?php echo $data23['principal_p'] ;?>`.

This is not the answer as I can see you are missing something when you try to assing the calculation to your DOM node.

[PHP.net json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
document.getElementsById("nprincipal").value = (principal*principal_p)/100;
```

or

```
document.getElementsById("nprincipal").innerHTML = (principal*principal_p)/100;
```